# No results when I execute my stored procedure on server with PHP 5.4 and driver MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, codeigniter-3, sqlsrv

In the last two days I faced this weird problem and I hope finding the answer here. I'm running a PHP application with codeigniter and when I execute my stored procedure in localhost with PHP 7.2 installed I get the results same when I execute it with direct query. But the same code is not running on the server with PHP 5.6 I get no results and no error. Every other procedure works just fine except for this one and I can't see how to solve it

Here is my localhost database configuration I'm using `sqlsrv` driver

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'IP Adress'; 
//$db['default']['port'] = 1433; // or the port you configured on step 6
 $db['default']['username'] = 'web_user';
 $db['default']['password'] = '*****';
 $db['default']['database'] = 'Test_ANPAP';
 $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
 $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
 $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; 
 $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
 $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
 $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
 $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
 $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
 $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Same for the server but driver is `mssql`

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
```

Here is the code I executed

```
$sp = " EXEC TAB_Assure_Select_New @StartDate = '2019-09-01', 
@EndDate = '2019-10-01'";
$result = $this->db->query($sp);
if($result->num_rows()>0)
    return $result->result_array();
else
    return false;// it 's always false on server
```

I also tried this, same no results

```
$conn = mssql_connect('IP address', 'web_user', '*****');
mssql_select_db('Test_ANPAP', $conn);

$proc = mssql_init("TAB_Assure_Select_New @StartDate = '01-09-2019', 
@EndDate = '01-10-2019'", $conn);
$proc_result = mssql_execute($proc);
$rows = mssql_fetch_array($proc_result);
print_r($rows);
print_r(mssql_num_rows($proc_result));
mssql_free_statement($proc);
```

Comment: Your call to `mssql_init` is not correct, can you test with the next statement: `<?php$sp = mssql_init('TAB_Assure_Select_New', $conn); if ($sp === false) {echo mssql_get_last_message(); exit;}; $startdate = '2019-09-01'; $enddate = '2019-10-01'; mssql_bind($sp, "@StartDate", $startdate, SQLVARCHAR, false); mssql_bind($sp, "@EndDate", $enddate, SQLVARCHAR, false); $result = mssql_execute($sp, false); if ($result === false) {echo mssql_get_last_message(); exit;} echo "OK";?>`

Comment: @Zhorov didn't work!

Comment: it didn't work, no results are returned ,no error returned , i test the same code with another stored procedure and it works , and the query return results but the code doesn't

Comment: none of my codes works , but the query on visual studio works fine and on localhost where I use sqlserv works too , i think the problem is in the driver mssql or in the procedure itself

Comment: Just a side note, but `mssql` extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

Comment: I usually do a check for possible multiple resultsets after `mssql_execute()` call: `do {while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {print_r($row, true);};} while (mssql_next_result($result));`.